# How to Embed a DocuSign Document into an ASP.Net MVC Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, embed, docusignapi

I'm trying to embed a DocuSign document into an ASP.Net MVC 4 page. Unfortunately, I do not have any guidance on how to do that. Could you refer me to the specific documentation on how to embed a DocuSign document and then how to detect when all the fields are signed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net I would first of all take a look at the DocuSign .NET SDK.

This is available throught NuGet

Eitherway, you are going to need to have the following built into your site:

- Envelope Creation Call (The recipient who is going to be the embedded signer needs to have clientid parameter specified as part of the call). Embedded signing is covered on the following page [Link](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign)
- Post Recipient View. This will return a url which you can place in an iframe. In the headers of this request you can specify return url parameters, which provide ways to capture when different events happen on the envelope. This call is covered on the following page: [Link](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm)